# Ошибка View. Circular view path

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, view

коллеги! Я новичок в Spring, и столкнулся с проблемой.
Необходимо реализовать функционал поиска по таблице (использую PostgreSQL).
Поиск заканчивается ошибкой:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   Circular view path [search]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/search] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)

Посмотрел подобные вопросы, ошибка чаще всего связана с отсутствием каких-либо зависимостей в pom.xml, но вроде бы все зависимости для JSP присутствуют. Подскажите, в чем проблема? Спасибо за вашу помощь!

Код DIV'a для поиска:

```
 <form class="form-inline" method="get" action="search">
  <i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <input class="form-control form-control-sm ml-3 w-75" type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="Поиск..." aria-label="Search" />
</form>
```

Код репозитория:

```
package book.repos;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import book.domain.Advice;

public interface AdviceRepo extends CrudRepository<Advice, Long> {

    List<Advice> findByIdTopic(long idTopic);

     @Query(value = "SELECT c FROM Advice c WHERE c.name LIKE '%' || :keyword || '%'"
                + " OR c.argument LIKE '%' || :keyword || '%'"
                + " OR c.law_argument LIKE '%' || :keyword || '%'")
        public List<Advice> search(@Param("keyword") String keyword);
}
```

Код сервиса:

```
package book.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import book.domain.Advice;
import book.repos.AdviceRepo;

@Service
@Transactional
public class AdviceService {
     @Autowired AdviceRepo adviceRepo;

       //Поиск
        public List<Advice> search(String keyword) {
            return adviceRepo.search(keyword);
        }
}
```

Код контроллера :

```
    @Controller
    public class AdviceController {

        @Autowired
        private AdviceRepo adviceRepo;

    @Autowired
    private AdviceService adviceService;
        @GetMapping("/search")
        public ModelAndView search(@RequestParam String keyword) {
            List<Advice> result = adviceService.search(keyword);
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("search");
            mav.addObject("result", result);

            return mav;    
        }

    }
```

Вьюшка:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>   
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Search Result</title>
</head>
<body>

<div align="center">
    <h2>Search Result</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
           <th>Проблема</th>
        <th>Решение</th>
        <th>Доп. информация</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${result}" var="advice">
        <tr>
            <td>${advice.name}</td>
            <td>${advice.argument}</td>
            <td>${advice.law_argument}</td>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>sweater</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
     <!-- Spring Boot starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <!-- Freemarker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <!-- DevTools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DataBase support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <!-- PostgreSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- websocket -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

           <!-- JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему следующим образом:
В application.properties надо было прописать spring.mvc.view.prefix и spring.mvc.view.suffix для jsp